# Cocos2d-x How to restrict the movement of the touch only to X or Y?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm building a simple match 3 game. I have a problem wherein sometimes when I move the cursor down it also goes a bit to the left or the right.
I try to restrict the movement to the X or the Y depending on where the initial movement of the drag goes, but I guess I'm missing something here.
What is the best way to detect the initial movement and strict it to that movement only:
here is what I have :

```
bool Gem::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{   
    CCPoint touchPoint = touch->getLocation();
    if (m_state != kPaddleStateUngrabbed)
    {

        return false;
    }
    if ( !containsTouchLocation(touch) ) 
    {

        return false;
    }    
    m_state = kPaddleStateGrabbed;
    TouchBeganPossitionY = touch->getLocation().y;
    TouchBeganPossitionX = touch->getLocation().x;
    std::string idd = getGemId();
    return true;
}

void Gem::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{

    CCAssert(m_state == kPaddleStateGrabbed, "Gem - Unexpected state!");    
    bMoveY = false;
    bMoveX = false;
    m_state = kPaddleStateUngrabbed;
    bMoveYContinue = true;
    bMoveXContinue = true;
    nextGem = NULL;
    isNextGemSelected = false;

} 
void Gem::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    CCPoint touchPoint = touch->getLocation();
    int colNum = -1;
    int rowNum = -1;
    float thisSpritePositionX = -1;
    float thisSpritePositionInPlaceX = -1;
    float thisSpritePositionY = -1;
    float thisSpritePositionInPlaceY = -1;
    colNum = getColNum();
    rowNum = getRowNum();
    thisSpritePositionX = this->mySprite->getPositionX();
    thisSpritePositionInPlaceX = this->getGemPos().x;
    thisSpritePositionY = this->mySprite->getPositionY();
    thisSpritePositionInPlaceY= this->getGemPos().y;

    if((touchPoint.y != TouchBeganPossitionY) && !bMoveX && bMoveYContinue)
    {
         //going down
        if((touchPoint.y < TouchBeganPossitionY) )
        {
            CCLOG("move down");
            if(!isNextGemSelected)
            {
                nextGem = getNextGemByRowAndCol(getRowNum()-1,getColNum());
                isNextGemSelected = true;
            }
            if(nextGem != NULL)
            {                
                /*
                 the touch move will be for few pixels , then the MoveBy action will take place
                 */
                float thisSpritePositionInPlaceYEstimate = (thisSpritePositionInPlaceY-positionPaddingExtend);
                if(thisSpritePositionY < thisSpritePositionInPlaceYEstimate)
                {
                    bMoveY = true;
                    mySprite->setPosition( ccp(mySprite->getPositionX(),touchPoint.y) );

                }
                else
                {
                    bMoveYContinue = false;
                    isNextGemSelected = false;
                    setPositionForGemOnDetect(nextGem,kMoveDown);
                }

            }
        }//End if((touchPoint.y < TouchBeganPossitionY) )
        else if(touchPoint.y > TouchBeganPossitionY)
        {
            CCLOG("move up");
            if(!isNextGemSelected)
            {
                nextGem = getNextGemByRowAndCol(getRowNum()+1,getColNum());
                isNextGemSelected = true;
            }
            if(nextGem != NULL)
            {
                /*
                 the touch move will be for few pixels , then the MoveBy action will take place
                 */
                float thisSpritePositionInPlaceYEstimate = (thisSpritePositionInPlaceY+positionPaddingExtend);
                if(thisSpritePositionY > thisSpritePositionInPlaceYEstimate)
                {
                    bMoveY = true;
                    mySprite->setPosition( ccp(mySprite->getPositionX(),touchPoint.y) );
                }
                else
                {
                    isNextGemSelected = false;
                    bMoveYContinue = false;
                    setPositionForGemOnDetect(nextGem,kMoveUp);
                }
            }
        }
    } //End if((touchPoint.y != TouchBeganPossitionY) && !bMoveX && bMoveYContinue) 
    else if((touchPoint.x != TouchBeganPossitionX) && !bMoveY && bMoveXContinue)
    {
        //Moving Right
        if((touchPoint.x > TouchBeganPossitionX) )
        {
            CCLOG("move right");
            if(!isNextGemSelected)
            {
                nextGem = getNextGemByRowAndCol(rowNum,colNum+1);
                isNextGemSelected = true;
            }
            if(nextGem != NULL)
            {
                /*
                 the touch move will be for few pixels , then the MoveBy action will take place
                 */

                float thisSpritePositionInPlaceXEstimate = (thisSpritePositionInPlaceX+positionPaddingExtend);
                if(thisSpritePositionX < thisSpritePositionInPlaceXEstimate)
                {
                    //bMoveXContinue = false;
                    bMoveX = true;   
                    mySprite->setPosition( ccp(touchPoint.x,mySprite->getPositionY()) );
                }
                else
                {
                    bMoveXContinue = false;
                    isNextGemSelected = false;
                    setPositionForGemOnDetect(nextGem,kMoveRight);
                }

            }

        }//End if((touchPoint.x > TouchBeganPossitionX) )
        else if(touchPoint.x < TouchBeganPossitionX)
        {
            CCLOG("move left");
            if(!isNextGemSelected)
            {
                nextGem = getNextGemByRowAndCol(rowNum,colNum-1);
                isNextGemSelected = true;
            }
            if(nextGem != NULL)
            {                

                float thisSpritePositionInPlaceXEstimate = (thisSpritePositionInPlaceX-positionPaddingExtend);
                if(thisSpritePositionX>thisSpritePositionInPlaceXEstimate)
                {

                    bMoveX = true;                    
                    mySprite->setPosition( ccp(touchPoint.x,mySprite->getPositionY()) );
                }
                else
                {
                    bMoveXContinue = false;
                    isNextGemSelected = false;
                    setPositionForGemOnDetect(nextGem,kMoveLeft);
                }                                 
            }
        }

    }//End else if((touchPoint.x != TouchBeganPossitionX) && !bMoveY && bMoveXContinue)
}
```

In short:
What I want is very simple , when there is detection even the smallest in Y axis , I want that the movement will be locked only to the Y axis with no option to move to the X axis until the finger is released. The same for X.

Comment: this looks like too much code for such a simple thing, and some things seem redundant like bMoveX and bMoveXContinue. I suggest to split the code that determines the movement of the drag from the code that moves the sprites and tests for intersection. Use logging to see where things fall apart. I'm pretty sure there's a logic bug that's hard to see due to the redundant nature of the code.

Comment: yes i know its lots of code , i also remove the logging from here 
i did test it , in 80 of the time it doing its job , but in the 20 % it sometimes move abit ot the X if i drag it to the Y

Comment: It could be just because you think you moved in Y but actually what was detected moved in X. You should consider adding a threshold like:



`const float threshold = 2.f;
if(touchPoint.x < TouchBeganPositionX - threshold)`